# Загрузить данные в текстовый редактор

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

На сайте установлен текстовый редактор CKEDIT, вот так я загружаю туда данные:
Сначала через **Ajax** принимаю в переменную (объект), а потом загружаю в редактор:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'Desc_UKR',{     
    extraPlugins:"autogrow",   
    removePlugins:"wsc,scayt,save,about"     
});   
CKEDITOR.replace( 'Desc_RUS',{   
    extraPlugins:"autogrow",    
    removePlugins:"wsc,scayt,save,about"   
});   
CKEDITOR.replace( 'Desc_ENG',{  
    extraPlugins:"autogrow",    
    removePlugins:"wsc,scayt,save,about"   
});

    setToEditor('Desc_UKR',course.Desc_UKR);
    setToEditor('Desc_RUS',course.Desc_RUS);
    setToEditor('Desc_ENG',course.Desc_ENG);
```

Но мне понадобилось всё же подключить **гланый-файл (по работе с БД)** к странице методом include, теперь выходит, страница загружается через **ajax (javascript формирует часть данных)**, а другую часть формирует сам **php**. Как-то не очень, я бы убрал ajax, но редактор **CKEDIT** принимает данные только через свои методы, никак иначе.

```
 CKEDITOR.instances[ID_TEXT_INPUT].setData('текст какой-то');
```

Я вот думаю: это нормально, что разными способами страница формируется? По-моему, нет...
Вот тогда я думаю решить проблему таким типом:

```
<php echo'
CKEDITOR.instances[ID_TEXT_INPUT].setData('текст какой-то');
';/>
```

Только этого текста, что я вставляю, бывает и по 5000 символом и не в одном экземпляре, так вот думаю, как поступить?